# Using regex over several lines in notepad++

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I am wanting to find the following set of html information in several hundred separate files:

```
{{> StartPageAvatar char="k"}}
<h3>{{> m1a35Intro}}</h3>
{{> duration3}}
```

No I can do all this separately with,

```
([^\w\*]{3,4 } StartPageAvatar char="([k,t,u,e,l]{1,4})"[^\w\*]{2})
(<h3>([^\w\*]{3,4 }m(.)a(.{1,2})Intro[^\w\*]{2})</h3>)
([^\w\*]{3,4 }duration(.)[^\w\*]{2})
```

What I cannot get is how to do all three lines at once, as I would like to use the variables **m1a35** to add in a new line above the three original. So the end result I would like to have:

```
<h1 class="start-page-header">{{> m1a35Title}}</h1>
{{> StartPageAvatar char="k"}}
<h3>{{> m1a35Intro}}</h3>
{{> m1a33Time}}
```

So I am deleting the {{duration#}} template and replacing it with an activity specific time template. The problem I am having is adding in the {{> m1a33Title}} line, as this needs to know what activity numbers it should be, which is provided by the line below.

I just cannot get the three regex expressions made to work together and do it all in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, this regex will do the work:

```
(\W{3,4}StartPageAvatar char="[ktuel]{1,4}"\W{2}).<h3>(\W{3,4}m.a.{1,2})Intro\W{2}<\/h3>.\W{3,4}duration.\W{2}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK4wE7/2)</kbd>

I changed:

- your char from `[k,t,u,e,l]` to `[ktuel]` (the comma isn't needed)
- your negation `[^\w\*]` to `\W` (but it missed the star)
- removed a few useless capturing groups

Don't forget to set the find & replace options of N++ to :

[image]

Comment: So very close, your example works brilliantly. I did a small adjustment to it as such: [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK4wE7/5). This works happily but on notepad++ it is not linking it, even though I have set it to regular expression and . matches newline.

Comment: @T.Eley `notepad++ it is not linking it` ?

Comment: not liking it sorry, It isn't find anything when I use it.

Comment: Well... Maybe it would be time to switch to another text editor (Sublime Text [for which the regex works] or Atom) or a real IDE... @T.Eley

Comment: I took your adivce and tried it out on sublime text 3, I'm still getting no luck unfortunately. The expression I used was:
(\W{3,4}StartPageAvatar char="[ktuel]{1,4}"\W{2}).<h3>(\W{3,4}m.a.{1,2})Intro\W{2}<\/h3>.\W{3,4}duration.\W{2}

and

/(\W{3,4}StartPageAvatar char="[ktuel]{1,4}"\W{2}).<h3>(\W{3,4}m.a.{1,2})Intro\W{2}<\/h3>.\W{3,4}duration.\W{2}/s

if I use just (\W{3,4}StartPageAvatar char="[ktuel]{1,4}"\W{2}) then I get results, it is the whole combination that is not working.

Comment: @T.Eley With st3 add (?s) in the beginning of the regex

Comment: (?s)(\W{3,4}StartPageAvatar char="[ktuel]{1,4}"\W{2}).<h3>(\W{3,4}m.a.{1,2})Intro\W{2}<\/h3>.\W{3,4}duration‌​.\W{2} Still not working. Sorry for being such a bother.

Comment: I've realise the issue, the regex is working perfectly. The issue I'm having now is some of the html lines have tab spaces in front of them which is then breaking the content.

Comment: (?s)[ \t]{0,}(\W{3,4}StartPageAvatar char="[ktuel]{1,4}"\W{2}).[ \t]{0,}<h3>(\W{3,4}m.a.{1,2})Intro\W{2}<\/h3>.[ \t]{0,}{\W{3,4}duration.\W{2} Fixes it nicely, I have it working now! You have been invaluable @Thomas Ayoub!